# Swift 4 Decodable - array with objects

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm consuming an API that looks like very similar to this:

```
{
   "email": "hello@example.com",
   "settings": [
        {
            "setting_A": {
                "value": -65,
            }
        },
        {
            "setting_B": {
                "value": {
                    "b1": {
                        "val": 12,
                        "unit": "kg"
                    },
                    "b2": {
                        "val": 10,
                        "unit": "g"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm stuck on decoding this JSON result esp. `settings`. Can someone help me how to?

This is what I have so far:

```
struct User: Decodable  {
  let email: String
  let settings: [Setting] // not sure how to do this :(
}
```

Comment: Are the keys inside settings always constant? Do the values corresponding to specific keys always have the same form? If not, do you know all possible keys and all possible values?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, the keys and values are always consistent. No dynamically added keys or values.

Comment: @ashokgelal you can convert your json to model class here https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Wow! I wish I knew this tool before. Just saved me few extra hours. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome  happy to help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending few hours, I ended up using https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift as suggested by @PrashantTukadiya and got it all done in under 5 minutes. I highly recommend using that tools for your encoding/decoding needs.

Comment: I also recommend to use this Xcode extension: https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype-xcode

Comment: This site uses `Data(contentsOf: url)` inside the model to get data from the network, which is an abomination. Otherwise, yeah, such a site could be useful, sure.